# Non Gridview event capture edit mode row index

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How can I get the index of a `gridview` row in edit mode from an event that is not a gridview event?

I have a DDL in a cell of the Gridview. When the DDL changes I want to perform an update to a label of another cell in the same row.

So I am using the `DDL_SelectedIndexChanged` Event and have everything working including the post to the label, but its always the frist row. What is the correct way to get the row index in edit mode from outside of a `gridview` event?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
protected void DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlcontrol = (DropDownList) sender;
    GridViewRow grrow = (GridViewRow) ddlcontrol.NamingContainer;
    int rowindex = grrow.RowIndex;
}
```